# serialize() is not working with my form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble serializing my form's data. Code below. Console just logs blank.

HTML:

```
<div id="sm-log-in">
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-4 small-centered columns">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="medium-2 columns">
                    <label for="username" class="inline">Username:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="medium-10 columns">
                    <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                    <!--<small class="error">A username is required.</small>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="medium-2 columns">
                    <label for="password" class="inline">Password:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="medium-10 columns">
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                    <!--<small class="error">A password is required.</small>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="columns">
                    <input id="remember-me" type="checkbox" class="right"><label for="remember-me" class="right">Remember Me</label>
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="row">
                <div class="columns">
                    <button type="submit" class="small right">Log In</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#sm-log-in form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();      
    console.log($( this ).serialize());
    //etc
```

Comment: Add 'name' attributes to your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add "name" attributes to each input element, like below:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">

<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
```

Answer (score 1):

Form fields need to have a `name` attribute. This is how the values are keyed. The `serialize` method pairs the name of each input with its values. Since none of them have any names, none of them are included.